# Why does the negative of the direction of steepest ascent result in the direction of steepest descent?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, gradient-descent

The gradient is a vector composed of partial derivatives and is a vector that gives the direction of the steepest ascent.

In a YouTube video that I was watching, it talked about how the gradient descent of the function $f(x,y)$ is $-\nabla f(x,y)$. It does not seem that very intuitive to me that the negative the gradient, or the direction of the steepest ascent, results in the direction of the steepest descent.

I can think of counter-examples to this statement, but I am unsure if I am understanding this part of the video correctly.

[Video link](https://youtu.be/IHZwWFHWa-w?t=525)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because $\nabla(-f)=-\nabla f$ is the direction of steepest ascent of the function $-f$, which is therefore the direction of steepest *descent* of $f$.

Comment: What about the case of this? https://www.google.com/search?q=hyperbolic+paraboloid&sxsrf=ALeKk00hfGW8oTM_yb-XFmUqY72AXtOX0g:1595911096488&tbm=isch&source=iu&ictx=1&fir=VVn227xmU8JNJM%252CPwPkRmCleP3CHM%252C_&vet=1&usg=AI4_-kT0d-f-qW27agS0nkSOcOtcn8nJ0g&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjL8v6PkO_qAhXhN30KHZqRBQ4Q_h0wAHoECAYQBA&biw=1280&bih=578#imgrc=VVn227xmU8JNJM This looks like a counter-example to the gradient descent equation.

Comment: @Jaden Lee Do you mean at the middle of the shape? At that point the gradient of the function is the vector $(0,0)$ and so the above is pretty meaningless.

Comment: is the gradient only (0,0) at the middle of the shape or of the parabola in the middle

Comment: @JadenLee Well, it's only flat right in the middle.

Comment: Wouldn't the function be steeper going -y direction than that +x direction?

Comment: @Jaden Lee Right in the middle, it not "steeper" in **any** direction. This follows from the definition of the gradient and the fact that it is the vector $(0,0)$ right in the middle.

Comment: I mean on the point near (0.5,0,0.5)

Comment: @Jaden Lee Ok well now it's just a matter of how you see the picture. This isn't really mathematics anymore. Is my answer unclear? Is there something else I can do to make it better?

Comment: No. Your answer is clear. I just thought that the hyperbolic paraboloid would be a counterexample to the gradient descent.