# is it wrong? -> using Gradient to get the steepest slope to go upwards, so in order get minimized loss we go the opposite

Tags: derivatives, gradient-descent

I am not good at mathematics and have been learning ML from Udacity.

In its tutorial video, the tutor says(I concluded it in a short way):

***using Gradient to get the steepest slope to go upwards, so in order get minimized loss we go the opposite.***

Here is the video starting from time 3:00:
https://youtu.be/9ILiZwbi9dA?t=179

my question is :
it is not necessary the exactly opposite direction of the gradient(steepest ascent) that the steepest descent goes. As it's 3D, if the gradients goes 0 degree, it doesn't necessary mean the 180 degree points you the steepest descent.
So I assume his statement is wrong?

Could someone correct me(using plain language even a laymen can understand, thanks) if I got wrong somewhere?

Thanks

**update**

After reading John's answer, my understanding is:

At the particular point ***P*** we can draw a tangent line A. Let's assume that the 0 degree of A points to the fastest direction for ascending, but the actual fastest direction for descending is 150 degree at point ***P***. Since the tangent line can ONLY have 2 directions which are 0 and 180, so we can only take 180 degree of the line A as our next direction for descending.

Is my understanding correct?

Comment: No, "actual fastest direction" of descent at that point cannot be $150^o$

Comment: @AkshatSharma could you please explain the reason?

Comment: One way to think about it is to imagine different tangent lines at $P$ corresponding to different directions, the line with the maximum slope would also be the line with minimum slope in opposite direction.

Comment: If your idea in the update is to consider the supposition that the steepest ascent direction is $0$ and the steepest descent is $150$ degrees, and then **reject** that supposition as a contradiction, then you have the right idea. Is that what you meant?

Comment: @AkshatSharma "the line with the maximum slope would also be the line with minimum slope in opposite direction". How can you prove this? I have difficulty of reasoning this point.

Comment: @DavidK I'm lost in your comment. the 150 degree is just an example, my point is that at point ***P*** it may not always be: 0 is the steepest ascent and 180 is the steepest descent. How do you get this conclusion? Could you please explain it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does the negative of the direction of steepest ascent result in the direction of steepest descent?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3771772/why-does-the-negative-of-the-direction-of-steepest-ascent-result-in-the-directio)

Comment: @JadenLee thanks man, I still don't quite understand the formula provided in that answer. But I can see that answer provides the explanation from mathematics aspect, so I will mug it up. Thanks for the link you provided, it does help. The answer from John Hughes provides me more intuition from the aspect of vision/imagination. Thus it is more easier for a laymen to understand.

Comment: Just in case you still aren't able to convince yourself, you may check this out and perhaps convince yourself after checking for all possible tangents at a point: https://www.geogebra.org/3d/mnueatbs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a function of two variables, $f(x,y),$ has a gradient at a particular point $(x_1,y_1)$, it implies that when you graph the function in three dimensions using the equation $z = f(x,y)$, there is a unique tangent plane to that graph at the point $P_1 = (x_1,y_z,f(x_1,y_1))$ that provides a very good approximation of the function $f$ near $(x_1,y_1)$.

In particular, if you travel along the surface of the three-dimensional graph in any direction from $P_1,$ your path initially is tangent to a straight line through $P_1$ and that line lies exactly in the tangent plane.

It is certainly possible to construct a function such that the steepest increase from some point $(x_1,y_1)$ in the $x,y$ plane is in the direction $0$ degrees from the positive $x$ axis direction, but the steepest decrease is in the direction $150$ degrees. For example, for  $(x_1,y_1)$ you could define $f(x,y) = \frac14 x$ everywhere in quadrants I, II, and IV in the plane, but in quadrant III you make a deep V-shaped groove or trough in the graph of the function, centered along the line that goes through the point $(0,0)$ at a $150$-degree angle so that if you travel along the center of the groove starting at $(0,0)$ you decrease $f(x,y)$ faster than if you just follow the plane in the direction $180$ degrees. But the fastest increase is still in the direction exactly along the $x$ axis, $0$ degrees.

Such a function exists, even a continuous function like that exists, but you can never find its gradient at $(0,0),$ because the groove means that no matter how small a neighborhood you pick around $(0,0),$ there are always function values in the groove that are too far below the tangent plane that all the function values in quadrants I, II, and IV lie on.

You can have a direction of steepest descent that is along a different line than the direction of steepest ascent. You can have a gradient. You can have neither of these things.
But you **cannot have both.**

An analogy in a one-variable function is the absolute value function,
$g(x) = \lvert x\rvert.$ We are told that the derivative of a function always tells us the direction in which the function increases; and if the derivative tells us the function increases when we increase $x$, then the function decrease when we decrease $x.$ But at $x = 0,$ the function $g(x)$ increases in both directions.
How can that be?
It is made possible by the fact that $g(x)$ **has no derivative** at $x = 0.$

Comment: I love that "you cannot have both" paragraph --- beautiful distillation of the facts.

Comment: Brilliant explanation. even a laymen like me starting to have a vision of the plane and 3D space you described here. So as you said, you cannot have both(steepest ascent and steepest descent) at one particular point, then it means : use negative gradient to find the steepest descent does not guarantee that the opposite side of gradient is the steepest descent, then why should we use negative gradient to find the steepest descent?

Comment: Maybe it is still not clear enough. You can have a gradient at a point and also have a steepest ascent and steepest descent that are 180 degrees apart. You **cannot** have a gradient and also have a steepest ascent and steepest descent that are **less than** 180 degrees apart. The things you would need to do in order to make the angle less than 180 degrees will necessarily break the conditions you need in order to have a gradient.

Comment: yes still not clear enough, sorry for my bad math-brain, so what are the "conditions" ??

Comment: In the formal definition of a gradient (for example in https://calculus.subwiki.org/wiki/Gradient_vector) there are certain facts that must be true about the function at the point where you want the gradient to exist. Those facts are the "conditions."

Comment: @DavidK I think you refer to this one: "Suppose f is a function of many variables. We can view f as a function of a vector variable. The gradient vector at a particular point in the domain is a vector whose direction captures the direction (in the domain) along which changes to f are concentrated, and whose magnitude is the directional derivative in that direction." ??

Comment: That's the motivational description of the gradient, explaining why it is interesting. The definition that actually says when a function can or cannot have a gradient is the "epsilon-delta" definition, which as you can see is not a very intuitive definition.

Answer (score 1):

What the speaker said was correct, "locally", which means that if you stand on a reasonably smooth part of a mountain, there's some path through the place you're standing -- call it $P$ -- that "climbs up fastest", right? One that gains altitude as fast as possible. If you drew that path on the ground in white paint, at the point $P$, you could draw a line tangent to the path. Going uphill along the tangent is the best thing you could do if you wanted to instantaneously gain altitude; going downhill along that tangent is the best thing you could do to instantaneously LOSE altitude. And because the tangent line is a straight line, those two ideal directions are 180 degrees apart.

Now the path that you've drawn in white paint may wander to the left and right a bit, so the best possible direction at $P$ may be different from the best possible direcition at $P'$, where $P'$ is 10 feet away from $P$. But if you're right AT the point $P$, those two "fastest rise" and "fastest fall" directions are in fact opposite.

One very important part of that claim is that the place on the mountainside where you're standing is "reasonably smooth". But it turns out that in the mathematical details, "having a gradient" is exactly the condition needed to be "reasonably smooth".

Comment: thanks John, my understanding of your answer is too long to be a comment, so I put it as an update in my question. Please have a look and correct my understanding. thanks